# how to append text in epiceditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, epiceditor

I'm trying to make some helper buttons similar to stackoverflow markdown editor in epiceditor

I tried this method but this actually overrides the actual file and not append to it

this is an example for bold button

```
$('.icon-bold').click(function(){
   editor.importFile('epiceditor', '**strong text**')
});
```

**How could i append a text to a file using epiceditor ?**

i think this solution is overkill in large files

```
 $('.icon-bold').click(function(){
   content = editor.exportFile('epiceditor');
   editor.importFile('epiceditor',content + '**strong text**')
 });
```

Comment: I am using this method of yours to append to the editor. I works well too.